# Possible to access Phonegap API within a iframe?

Tags: iframe, mobile, cross-domain, cordova

I'm testing how to use the camera of a blackberry (5) with a phonegap app that has a iframe in it.

Basically the iframe calls for the camera, take a picture and return the picture to the iframe.

I don't know if it is possible to access phonegap APIs from within a iframe.

I put a simple cross domain test ( with two pages able to send messages back and forth ) on the simulator and it does not seem to work.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with iframes you are restricted to the same orign policy - meaning that you can only communicate beetween the frames if they load from the same server (event port is important here). A good sum up can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

From phonegaps point of view it would be very bad if a html file which is not index.html could acccess the camera. This would give all webpages the ability to take a foto when you visit them with a phonegap app. So therefore this is restricted to only index.html (on android and iOs, don't know about Blackberry)

Comment: thanks, got the camera working on blackberry 6 with cross domain messaging from the inner frame. =)

Comment: even with postMessage and HTML5, you can't communicate between phonegap and iframes?